# Concatenating .txt files into a .csv with bash

Tags: bash, csv, concatenation

I currently have three files **file1.txt**, **file2.txt**, **file3.txt** which I would like to join into one file **bigfile.csv**

The current format of the files are:

file1.txt

```
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100
```

file2.txt

```
441343******6401
100052******0314
100051******2784
100056******7772
```

file2.txt

```
150000
150000
100000
5000
```

The desired output is

```
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100;>441343******6401;150000
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
paste -d ';' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > bigfile.csv
```

Example Output:

```
$ cat bigfile.cvs
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100;441343******6401;150000
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100;100052******0314;150000
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100;100051******2784;100000
28-02-14 17:50:58 01401009 17756100;100056******7772;5000
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 paste -d ";" file1.txt <(sed s/^/\>/ file2.txt) file3.txt
```

the second file is updated to insert `>`.  If that was a typo, simply

```
paste -d ";" file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: If you click on [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31436165/revisions) you'll see that the `>` in the desired output is a typo made by Marc B's edit.  There is no need for you to have `sed` in the command, at all.