# Concatenate txt files' title and contents into two-column csv, bash

Tags: bash, csv, export-to-csv, gcloud, gsutil

While [similar questions have been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436165/concatenating-txt-files-into-a-csv-with-bash), I'm awkwardly struggling for my particular situation. In a gcloud bucket I'm accessing through a virtual machine I'm ssh'd into, I've got multiple folders each containing multiple txt files, each full of unique unstructured text. E.g.,

```
folder1/txt1.txt
"lorem ipsum lorem ip"
   
folder1/txt2.txt
"lorem ip ip ip
lorrrrr                         um
ip ip"

folder2/txt1.txt
"loremmmmmmm"
```

I've got to turn each folder into a single two-column csv, where column 1 is the filename, and column 2 is the contents of the file with spacing preserved. E.g.,

```
folder1.csv
"txt1, lorem ipsum lorem ip,
 txt2, lorem ip ip ip/    lorrrrr                         um/    ip ip"

folder2.csv
"txt1, loremmmmmmm"
```

For a single folder, something that gets me 25% there is:

```
gsutil cat gs://bucket/folder1/*.txt > folder1.csv
```

But this seems to remove the structure in a bad way, treating lines as just lines:

```
folder1.csv
"lorem ipsum lorem ip
lorem ip ip ip
lorrrrr                         um
ip ip"
```

And obviously doesn't even get started with filenames, which can be gathered independently with:

```
(in /folder1/ ) ls > folder1_filenames.csv
```

Really, if I can just get the spacing issues worked out with the txt files' content, I could cleanly create and then merge 2 1-column csv's for each folder: one for the filenames of the txts, and one for the content of the txts, since per-folder the two csvs' would have the exact same length and match cleanly.

I'll continue reading now, but I imagine that this is obvious to somebody more familiar with the syntax.